# Сдвинуть изображение на определённое количество пикселей в JS

Tags: javascript

В зависимости от того, куда пользователь нажмёт на поле, туда должен поставиться крестик либо нолик. Вот пытаюсь с крестиком сделать (`40px - длина стороны 1 квадрата`). Координаты квадрата это `xQwad` и `yQwad`.

```
function select() { // обработка нажатия на поле
//alert(event.offsetX + 'x' + event.offsetY);
var crossOrNo = localStorage["crossOrNo"],
    field = localStorage["field"],
    xQwad = (event.offsetX / 40) - ((event.offsetX / 40) % 1),
    yQwad = (event.offsetY / 40) - ((event.offsetY / 40) % 1);

field[xQwad][yQwad] = crossOrNo;
localStorage["field"] = field;
if (crossOrNo == 1) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "cross.png";
    img.width = 40;
    img.height = 40;
    document.getElementById("fieldOnWeb").innerHTML = "<img src='cross.png' style='height: 40px; width: 40px;' />";
    localStorage["crossOrNo"] = 0;
}
else if (crossOrNo == 0)
        localStorage["crossOrNo"] == 1;
 //alert(xQwad + 'x' + yQwad);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось проще чем я думал вот так можно (просто пара плюсов):

```
document.getElementById("fieldOnWeb").innerHTML = "<img src='cross.png' style='height: 40px; width: 40px; padding-left: " + xQwad * 40 + "px; padding-top: " + yQwad * 40 + "px' />";
```

Comment: Ну margin уж, а не padding, наверное?